# Simulate a realistic Bounce in JavaFX animation

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a Bouncing Ball Animation with JavaFX similar to the bouncing windows logo screen saver. The code I have now is decent but it will only bounce the ball in a clockwise manner. This is good generally but eventually the ball works itself around to a counter-clockwise rotation in which case it no longer looks realistic. I am stuck trying to find a way to calculate how the ball should bounce; in my mind it really comes down to what angel the ball comes in at. I am Using an `AnimationTimer` which `Translates` the ball a set amount each frame. When the `Bounds` of the ball meet a boundary the translating direction is changed it is at this meeting that I need a suggestion...
BallAnimation is an inner class.

```
    class BallAnimation extends AnimationTimer{
     private final Sphere ball;
     private double movex = 0;
     private double movey = 0;
     private double xvariation = 0;
     private double yvariation = 0;
     private boolean right = true;
     private boolean up = false;
     private boolean changeColorRandomly = true;

    private double rate = 1;



    public BallAnimation(Sphere ball){
        this.ball = ball;
        ball.setLayoutX(200);
        ball.setLayoutY(50);
    }

    public void handle(long now){
        move(right,up);

        Bounds ballBounds = ball.localToScene(ball.getBoundsInLocal());

        if(ballBounds.intersects(rightWall.getBoundsInParent())){
            calculateMotion(rightWall);  
            randomBounceAngle();
            setRandomColor(); 
        }
        if(ballBounds.intersects(leftWall.getBoundsInParent())){
            calculateMotion(leftWall);
            randomBounceAngle();
            setRandomColor(); 
        }
        if(ballBounds.intersects(ceiling.getBoundsInParent())){
            calculateMotion(ceiling);
            randomBounceAngle();
            setRandomColor(); 
        }
        if(ballBounds.intersects(floor.getBoundsInParent())){
            calculateMotion(floor);
            randomBounceAngle();
            setRandomColor(); 
        }


    }

    private void calculateMotion(Line touchedWall){
        if(touchedWall.equals(rightWall)){
            right = false;
            up = false;

        }
        if(touchedWall.equals(leftWall)){
            right = true;
            up = true;
        }
        if(touchedWall.equals(ceiling)){
            right = true;
            up = false;
        }
        if(touchedWall.equals(floor)){
            right = false;
            up = true;
        }



    }

    public void move(boolean right, boolean up){
        if(right && !up){
            ball.setTranslateX((movex += (getRate() + xvariation)));
            ball.setTranslateY((movey += (getRate() + yvariation)));  
        }
        if(right && up){
            ball.setTranslateX((movex += (getRate() + xvariation)));
            ball.setTranslateY((movey -= (getRate() + yvariation)));
        }
        if(!right && up){
            ball.setTranslateX((movex -= (getRate() + xvariation)));
            ball.setTranslateY((movey -= (getRate() + yvariation)));
        }
        if(!right && !up){
            ball.setTranslateX((movex -= (getRate() + xvariation)));
            ball.setTranslateY((movey += (getRate() + yvariation)));
        }
        System.out.println("("+movex+", "+movey+")");

    }

    public double getRate(){
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(double rate){
        this.rate = rate; 
    }

    public void randomBounceAngle(){
        double ran = Math.random();
        if(ran >= .50){
            //shallow bounce angle
            xvariation = 3;
            yvariation = 2;

        }else{
            //sharp bounce angle
            xvariation = 2;
            yvariation = 3;
        }
    }
```

[image: ![bouncing ball[1]]

... The problem is when the ball hits the right boundary it bounces down and away, the bottom it bounces up and left, left boundary: up and right, ceiling: right and down. This is fine most of the time but sometimes it needs to bounce the other way.

Comment: @jewelsea I think you find this interesting

Answer (score 2):

Well, in a world of perfect physics, in angle is equal to out angle.  If you are using an x/y axis, For reflection off the x-axis, negate the y component of the ball's velocity. For reflection off the y-axis, negate the x component of the ball's velocity.

I re-wrote pong in javascript using layers and detecting keyboard strokes for paddle control (this was in '00 or '01 with Netscape 4.7x).  I cheated, and set up functions to move the ball in 8 directions.  If the ball was traveling along an axis (straight left/right or up/down) a quick random number provided a different bounce coming out.  Otherwise, bounce out at same angle in.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function to reflect a vector around a normal.  It can be used to create a bounce, by reflecting the velocity vector of the ball around the normal of the wall (or the normal of the side of another object) that the ball is bouncing off of.

```
private Point2D reflect(Point2D vector, Point2D normal) {
    return vector.subtract(normal.multiply(vector.dotProduct(normal) * 2));
}
```

It is part of an implementation for a [sample breakout game](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/910dae32ef6d1bd4257850031aefcba2#file-breakoutgame-java-L302) I created based on the example code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278968/too-many-collisions-for-breakout-game-with-javafx).

The code shown for the vector-based reflection uses the formula provided in the answer to this question, which is translated directly to JavaFX classes:

- [How to get a reflection vector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13261/how-to-get-a-reflection-vector)
- =−2(⋅) where ⋅ is the dot product and  must be normalized.

Please note that, if you search, there are many math tutorials and Stackoverflow questions that talk about functions and methods for performing reflection.

A particular case for balls bouncing off vertical or horizontal surfaces such as walls or bricks in a breakout game is that the lines which the ball is bouncing off of are parallel to the x and y axes of the coordinate system, so the bounce can be performed by negating the x or y values of the velocity vector.  See the [example code in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278968/too-many-collisions-for-breakout-game-with-javafx) or answers to other questions on reflection for an example of this simplification if it is something you wish to use.

```
if (topWall) {
    dy = dy * -1;
}
            
if (leftWall || rightWall) {
    dx = dx * -1;
}

if(bottomWall) {
    dy = dy * -1;
}
```