# Too Many Collisions for Breakout Game with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to recreate the Breakout game. The ball bounces and collision is detected. However, too many collisions are happening at once. The ball destroys more than one brick at a time.

I started with a circle as the ball but then changed it to a rectangle to help get a more acurate collision detection. But that does not fully solve the problem.

I have tried to reverse the Y coordinate when collision is detected. So that once the object collides, the ball heads back to the paddle. But that does not fully solve the problem. I want to prevent back to back collsions. I've looked at similar posts but they don't help me. Any suggestions?

```
package breakoutgame;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;


public class BreakoutGame extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) {
        //creates main layout
    
        Pane layout= new Pane();
        layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        layout.setPrefSize(610,400); 
    
        Scene view= new Scene(layout);
    
        //creates components and adds them to the main layout
    
        ArrayList<Rectangle> allBricks = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int x=0; x<10; x++) {
            for(int y=0; y<8; y++) {
                Rectangle brick=new Rectangle(60,15);
                if(y<=1){
                    brick.setFill(Color.RED);
                }
                if(y>1 && y<=3){
                    brick.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
                }
                if(y>3 && y<=5){
                    brick.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                }
                if(y>5 && y<8){
                    brick.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                }
                brick.setLayoutX(x*62);
                brick.setLayoutY((16*y)+35);
                layout.getChildren().add(brick);
                allBricks.add(brick);
            }
        }
        Rectangle ball= new Rectangle(20,20, Color.BLUE);
        ball.relocate(300, 200);
    
        Rectangle paddle= new Rectangle(90,7, Color.ORANGERED);
        paddle.relocate(275, 390);
     
        layout.getChildren().addAll(paddle, ball);
     
        //controls paddle movement
    
       int movement = 15;
    
        view.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                if(paddle.getLayoutX() < 0) {
                     paddle.setLayoutX(paddle.getLayoutX()+movement);
                }
                paddle.setLayoutX(paddle.getLayoutX()-movement);
            }

            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                if(paddle.getLayoutX() > 510) {
                     paddle.setLayoutX(510);
                } 
                paddle.setLayoutX(paddle.getLayoutX()+movement);
            }
         });
    
        //creates an indefinite bouncing ball
    
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new 
        KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20), 
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            double dx = 5; 
            double dy = 3; 
        
           @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                //ball movement
                ball.setLayoutX(ball.getLayoutX() + dx);
                ball.setLayoutY(ball.getLayoutY() + dy);
            
                boolean leftWall = ball.getLayoutX() <= 0; 
                boolean topWall = ball.getLayoutY() < 35;
                boolean rightWall = ball.getLayoutX() >= 590;
                boolean bottomWall = ball.getLayoutY() >= 380;
            
                // If the top wall has been touched, the ball reverses direction.
                if (topWall) {
                   dy = dy * -1;
                }
            
                // If the left or right wall has been touched, the ball reverses direction.
                if (leftWall || rightWall) {
                    dx = dx * -1;
                }
                if(bottomWall) {
                    dy = dy * -1;
                }
            
                //if ball collides with paddle
                if (collide(paddle)) {
                dy = -dy;
                }
                
                //if ball and brick collides, remove brick
            
                Rectangle temp=null;
                for(Rectangle brick:allBricks) { 
                    if(collide(brick)) {
                        temp=brick;
                        layout.getChildren().remove(brick);
                        dy=-dy;
                    }
                }
                allBricks.remove(temp);
                temp=null;
            }
            public boolean collide(Rectangle other) {
                Shape collisionArea = Shape.intersect(ball, other);
                return collisionArea.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1;
            }
        }));
   
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
 
        window.setTitle("Breakout Game!");
        window.setScene(view);
        window.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Offhand, I don't see the error in your code, can you provide a [mcve] for this, something minimal which could be copy and pasted and run without change?  It would save time in helping people to answer your question and you would be more likely to get an answer that helps.

Comment: I've add a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Just put a "break" statement in your "if (collide(brick))" block.  Also, the way it's written now, you can remove multiple bricks from the layout, but only one brick from "allBricks".  I'd get rid of the "temp" variable and just remove the brick from "allBricks" at the same time.

Comment: @DaveB                                                                  `for(Rectangle brick:allBricks) { 
                    if(collide(brick)) {
                        layout.getChildren().remove(brick);
                        allBricks.remove(brick);
                        dy=-dy;
                        break;
                    }
                }'  still allows mutiple bricks to be removed

Comment: FYI: I created a [refactored version of your code in a gist](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/910dae32ef6d1bd4257850031aefcba2).

Answer (score 2):

I added some System.out.println() calls  to see when the ball is moving and when the bricks are hit.  I don't see any double hits from the same move, but I do see it sometimes hitting a second brick *after* bouncing off another brick.

I'd done some other refactoring just to make it easier for me to follow how it works, so that's what you get here:

```
public class BreakoutGame extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) {
        Pane layout = new Pane();
        layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        layout.setPrefSize(610, 400);
        Scene view = new Scene(layout);
        layout.getChildren()
              .addAll(IntStream.range(0, 10)
                               .boxed()
                               .flatMap(x -> IntStream.range(0, 8).mapToObj(y -> createBrick(x, y)))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        Rectangle ball = new Rectangle(20, 20, Color.BLUE);
        ball.relocate(300, 200);
        Rectangle paddle = new Rectangle(90, 7, Color.ORANGERED);
        paddle.relocate(275, 390);

        layout.getChildren().addAll(paddle, ball);

        int movement = 15;

        view.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                paddle.setLayoutX(paddle.getLayoutX() - movement * ((paddle.getLayoutX() < 0) ? -1 : 1));
            }
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                paddle.setLayoutX((paddle.getLayoutX() > 510) ? 510 : (paddle.getLayoutX() + movement));
            }
        });

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            double dx = 5;
            double dy = 3;

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                ball.setLayoutX(ball.getLayoutX() + dx);
                ball.setLayoutY(ball.getLayoutY() + dy);
                if (ball.getLayoutY() < 35 || collide(paddle)) {
                    dy = dy * -1;
                }
                if (ball.getLayoutX() <= 0 || ball.getLayoutX() >= 590) {
                    dx = dx * -1;
                }
                if (ball.getLayoutY() >= 380) {
                    dy = dy * -1;
                }
                System.out.println("Move: [" + ball.getLayoutX() + ", " + ball.getLayoutY() + "]");
                layout.getChildren()
                      .stream()
                      .filter(child -> (child != paddle) && (child != ball))
                      .filter(brick -> collide((Rectangle) brick))
                      .findFirst()
                      .ifPresent(brick -> {
                          System.out.println("******************-> Collide " + brick.getId());
                          layout.getChildren().remove(brick);
                          dy = -dy;
                      });
            }

            public boolean collide(Rectangle other) {
                return Shape.intersect(ball, other).getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1;
            }
        }));

        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();

        window.setTitle("Breakout Game!");
        window.setScene(view);
        window.show();

    }

    @NotNull
    private Rectangle createBrick(int x, int y) {
        Rectangle brick = new Rectangle(60, 15);
        brick.setFill(switch (y) {
            case 0, 1 -> Color.RED;
            case 2, 3 -> Color.ORANGE;
            case 4, 5 -> Color.GREEN;
            default -> Color.YELLOW;
        });
        brick.setLayoutX(x * 62);
        brick.setLayoutY((16 * y) + 35);
        brick.setId("[" + x + ", " + y + "]");
        return brick;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```